# Value range for AVCodecContex::global_quality, ::compression_level and AVFrame::quality

Tags: c++, ffmpeg, libav

I'm trying to compress video using different codecs (WMV, MP4, H264, VP8, VP9) using FFmpeg / libav. I'm unsure on how to set the global and per-frame quality values. Even the range of values is unclear to me. The docs are not helpful.
Currently I'm using:

```
AVCodecContex::global_quality = FF_QP2LAMBDA * quality; // no idea about range, default seems to be 0
AVCodecContex::compression_level = 0; // There is FF_COMPRESSION_DEFAULT (-1), which seems to be the default
AVFrame::quality = FF_LAMBDA_MAX * quality; // docs say range is [1, FF_LAMBDA_MAX], default seems to be 0
```

quality is in the range [0,1], where 0 means best image quality. Only 0 seems to do anything for me and leads to ok-quality videos. All other values produce low-quality output.
Any clarification on how to set these values is welcome.

Comment: global_quality is ignored by modern encoders, compression_level also is only used by some encoders. Look up encoder-specific tatecontrol options.

Comment: Could you throw in a link? I don't care much about bitrate control, I'd rather have a universal single quality value to adjust.

Comment: There isn't a single quality value to adjust. x264 has CRF and can't be used alongwith bitrate.. VP8/9 have CRF but some bitrate always has to be set...etc